# How to make a backup of a gitlab group?

Tags: gitlab, backup

I have a gitlab group with some repositories and issues and I would like to make a backup of the whole group.

I was looking at the doc. from gitlab but it's confusing for me and I don't know where to start.

When I run this command it creates a 300Kb .tar file but the group is larger than that, where do I specify the URL of the gitlab group I want to backup?

```
sudo gitlab-backup create
```

Comment: Are you using gitlab.com or a self-hosted gitlab instance?

Comment: im using gitlab.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the SaaS service on gitlab.com there isn't really a procedure to "backup" your data. Generally, you rely on GitLab to ensure your data is always available on gitlab.com

There is documentation for [backup and restore processes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html) but this applies to self-hosted GitLab instances only. (this is probably why you aren't able to figure out using the gitlab backup tools because they are intended for self-hosted instances only).

If you still want to backup your data that is on gitlab.com, one option might be to do a [file-based export of a group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/import_export.html). However, this procedure is deprecated and import support may be removed entirely in the future. Another option may be to "migrate" your groups following the [group migration documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/index.html) onto a self-hosted GitLab instance, then backup that self-hosted instance using the backup and restore process linked above.

Other than this, it is also possible to [export projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/import_export.html) to create zip archives that can later be imported to GitLab. This will include repository data, issues, etc. You can't do this in a single operation for your whole group, but you can export each project in your group individually, if you want.